# how to make UIImage as NULL in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have used the code :
`UIImage *selectedImage;`

then,

```
for (int j = 1 ; j <=b ; j++){
        id subView = [self.view viewWithTag:j];

        if ([subView isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]){
            ((UIImageView *)subView).image = selectedImage;
```

then how to make the UIImage as null value.

Comment: you want to remove it from view or just want to set empty image?

Comment: how to do that code

Comment: It isn't clear what do you want? Which image do you want to make NULL? selectedImage ?

Comment: uiimage names as selectedimage

Comment: ((UIImageView *)subView).image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@""]; this will set an empty image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to clear the image stored in UIImage objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439689/how-to-clear-the-image-stored-in-uiimage-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `UIImage` NULL set the Image as Empty Image

`[UIImage imageNamed:@""]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply set your image to null, just do :

`yourImage = nil;`

If I missunderstood the question or if I'm wrong do not hesitate to let me know. :)